# How to automatically delete QSettings after application is closed?

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I'm trying to use QSettings and QTemporaryFile to check if the user is logged into two applications at the same time. Every time the user logs in, I use this:

```
QTemporaryFile tmpFile;
tempFile.open();
QSettings sessionSettings(tempFile.fileName(), QSettings::IniFormat);

if(!sessionSettings.value("activeUser").toBool()){
   sessionSettings.setValue("activeUser", 1);
   return false;
}

return true;
```

I would like the QSettings to be deleted or cleared after the application is closed. That way the user can only log into one application at a time. How can I do that?

Comment: How do you share file name between processes? Also you can't guarantee that the file will be removed if your program crashes. Consider using [QtSingleApplication](https://github.com/itay-grudev/SingleApplication)

Comment: As @Genjutsu noted if your application crashes, this mechanism falls apart and the user will not be able to log since the `ini` file would still be present. `QtSingleApplication` is certainly a way. Another way would be using `QLockFile`.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest method would probably be calling `QFile::remove()` on the file when the application closes, e.g. by including it in some kind of "shutdown" function that is called at the end of the application (beware of crashes though, as the file would persist then)

As Genjutsu said, it is probably a better idea to use e.g. [SingleApplication](https://github.com/itay-grudev/SingleApplication) which essentially sets up a shared memory, ensuring that the state of the application is properly detected, even in the event of crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this right in your `main` function after `app.exec()`. Something like this:

```
int main() {
    QApplication a;
    ...........
    int ret = a.exec();
    //clear settings here
    return ret;
}
```